# How to return a single record from a database table based on id in lua?

Tags: database, lua

local function getListRecord(id)

```
    local select_stmt = db:prepare("SELECT * FROM list where id = ?")

     select_stmt:bind_values(id)
     select_stmt:step()
    local r = select_stmt:get_uvalues()

    select_stmt:finalize()

  return r

end
```

for the above code i am getting duplicate record created. how can i return single record
Please help me, thanks in advance

Thank you,
Madan mohan.

Answer (score 1):

Use of [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) is one way. Another may be to use [LIMIT 1](http://www.google.com/?q=select%20limit%201). The syntax and options may vary depending on which database you run the query against.

Examples:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM list where id = ?
SELECT * FROM list where id = ? LIMIT 1
```